# Is there any way to add a shortcut key in eclipse from plugin on runtime?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin in eclipse .  Currently we are using "org.eclipse.ui.bindings" extension point for providing shortcut keys . But it's a static option for providing shortcut key for action . Our user's face some difficulty to using my plugin without shortcut keys . Is there any option to add a shortcut keys on runtime via eclipse plugin ?.

```
 <extension      
       point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
       <category
             name="ZMedia Shortcuts Category"
             id="com.zmedia.viewer.commands.category">
       </category>

       <command
             name="Update Zmedia Deployable Instances"
             categoryId="com.zmedia.viewer.commands.category"
             id="com.zmedia.viewer.commands.UpdateZmediaDeployableInstances">
       </command>
 </extension>
 <extension
       point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
    <handler
          class="com.zmedia.viewer.handlers.UpdateZmediaDeployableInstances"
          commandId="com.zmedia.viewer.commands.UpdateZmediaDeployableInstances">
    </handler>
 </extension>
 <extension
       point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
    <key
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        commandId="com.zmedia.viewer.commands.UpdateZmediaDeployableInstances"
        sequence="M1+M2+ESC">
    </key>      
 </extension>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [extension point description](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_bindings.html) explicitly denies that:

> API Information:
>   **There is no public API for defining bindings**. To try to achieve stability for the user, bindings are only defined through the extension points. If you are an RCP application, you should be able to override this behaviour in the WorkbenchAdvisor.